# References about Boundary Conditions ADM Relativity (Thiemann)

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, boundary-conditions

I'm reading chapter $1.5.1$ (Section about Boundary Conditions) at Thiemann's Loop Quantum Gravity book and its taking a while to understand whats going on.

1. Along page 61 there's statements like $\mathcal L_{N} q_{a b}= O( r^{-2})$ odd/even. What it means?
2. At page 62 is stated that the boundary term in (1.5.1)
   $$g_{\mu \nu}=\eta_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{r}f_{\mu \nu}(t,x/r) + O\left(\frac{1}{r²}\right) \qquad (1.5.1)$$
   is exact, "that is,
   $$2\int_{\partial \sigma} dS_b N^a \delta P^a_b = \kappa \delta \vec P(\vec N) \qquad \vec P(\vec N)= \frac{2}{\kappa} \int_{\partial \sigma} dS_b N^a \delta P^a_b "\qquad (1.5.6)$$
   But I didn't understood what is the boundary term in $(1.5.1)$ and what he means with exact using $(1.5.6)$.

There are more questions but those are the principal and I think it would help me a lot having some other reference about this study of boundary terms in ADM Formalism.

So I'd be glad for any reference (book, article, notes) that could help me to understand this section $1.5.1$. I already found some articles on arxiv but they jump to ashtekar variables right on the beginning and that not what I want.